# Изменить url при переносе на локалхост

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать копию сайта на локалхост.
Сайт перенесен. БД подключены. Но возникает проблемма: когда с локалхоста захожу в админку, редеректит на админку сайта.
Понимаю, что нужно поменять старые url'ы. Но доступа к админке нет(редиректит), а sql-запросы к бд ломают сайт, но не помогают.
Как можно руками поменять url'ы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего нужно поправить файл wp-config.php

```php
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Благодарю. Помогло.